# How to initialize a HashMap with TreeSets as values?

Tags: java, hashmap, treeset

I am trying to create a HashMap using strings as keys and tree sets sorted using a custom comparator (CandidateComparator) as values.

```
HashMap<String, TreeSet<Candidate>> map = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Candidate>(new CandidateComparator())>();
```

I can't see what I've done wrong. I was using this site:

http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treeset/sort-by-objects/

as a reference.

This statement yields two syntax errors:

**1. Insert '>' to complete ReferenceType1;**

**2. Expression expected after this token '('** - refers to the last '(' of the statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Each `TreeSet` value will have its own `Comparator`. There's no way to force all values to be initialized the same way. Just `new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Candidate>>()`.

Comment: The TreeSet on the right is just a type, you can't pass arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

The HashMap should be initialized this way:

```
HashMap<String, TreeSet<Candidate>> map = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Candidate>>();
```

No Comparator is required for the HashMap itself. You'll need instances of `TreeSet` to populate the `HashMap`, and each of them would require a Comparator.

```
Comparator<Candidate> cmp = new CandidateComparator();
TreeSet<Candidate> ts1 = new TreeSet<Candidate>(cmp);
... populate ts1 ...
map.put ("someKey1", ts1);
TreeSet<Candidate> ts2 = new TreeSet<Candidate>(cmp);
... populate ts2 ...
map.put ("someKey2", ts2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparator` refers to the `TreeSet`, not the `HashMap`. Moreover, the `Comparator` is not part of the `TreeSet`'s type definition (as is, for example `TreeSet<Candidate>`) - it's only passed when a new instance is created.

So, to make a long story short - drop it from the definition and pass it when you construct an object:

```
Map<String, TreeSet<Candidate>> map = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Candidate>>();

map.put ("SomeString", new TreeSet<Candidate>(new CandidateComparator()));
```